# Pass a variable in IPython / Jupyter to a block of html (%%html)

Tags: python, html, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I would like to pass a simple variable to an html cell on Jupyter:

## cell 1:

```
a=5
```

## cell 2:

```
%%html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.alert(a);
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

This will return an error:

```
Javascript error adding output!
ReferenceError: a is not defined
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a hacky solution:

```
a=5

html_code ="""
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.alert(%s);
    </script>
  </head>
</html>""" % a

from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(html_code)
```